# How many four digit numbers are multiples of 4 but not 8? All the digits should be non-zero.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know that the number must be 4 mod 8. Excluding the non-zero part, there are 9000 4-digit numbers, out of which 1125 satisfy this property. But I don't know how to work out the non-zero part. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\overline{abcd}\equiv4\mod8$, then we have:

$\overline{cd}\equiv4\mod8$ when $\overline{ab}$ is even ($\overline{cd}$ can only be $12, 28, 36, 44, 52, 68, 76, 84, 92$);

$\overline{cd}\equiv0\mod8$ when $\overline{ab}$ is odd ($\overline{cd}$ can only be $16, 24, 32, 48, 56, 64, 72, 88, 96$).

Then do a simple calculation we know there are $9*81=729$ such numbers.

Comment: I know the answer is correct but..

Comment: Why did you multiply by 81 in last step?

Comment: Because there are 90 2-digit numbers, 9 of them have a zero digit ($10, 20, ..., 90$). Thus, there are $90-9=81$ such $\overline{ab}$ where all digits are non-zero.

Comment: oh, right. Thanks!